# generate tabindex dynamically for table row input elements

Tags: jquery, jsp

I need to generate tabindex for required elements in a table as the rows generate from foreach loop with three element in a row...

```
<table id="cart-table" class="form-group mb0 center-al check-number" role="grid">
<c:forEach items="${xyz.abc}" var="entry" varStatus="status">
<tr class="entry-row">
        <td class="col-product-reason">
            <select id="select${entry.index}"   class="form-control" >
                <option value="${entry.displayCode}">
                    ${entry.displayValue}
                </option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td class="col-product-quantity">
            <span><input type="text" id="quantity1-${entry.index}" class="small-input form-control"/></span>
            <span><input type="text" id="quantity2-${entry.index}" class="small-input form-control"/></span>
        </td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```

This is my code snippet, i have tried myself to generate tabindex in the following  way

```
<tr><td><select tabindex="0">//options</select></td><td><input type="text" tabindex="1"/><input type="text" tabindex="2"/></td></tr>
<tr><td><select tabindex="3">//options</select></td><td><input type="text" tabindex="4"/><input type="text" tabindex="5"/></td></tr>
<tr><td><select tabindex="6">//options</select></td><td><input type="text" tabindex="7"/><input type="text" tabindex="8"/></td></tr>
```

But i couldn't come up with a logic to solve this.. Please provide me with any ideas

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `<td><c:out value="${status.count}" /></td>` after `<tr class="entry-row">`.